# Change the selection of results per page on local xml

Tags: magento-1.9, page

I have to change the results per page option on my products page. The results per page drop down must show 3,12,21 and right now it's 12,24,36. I have to change it using only the local.xml file. I'm using magento 1.9.

Comment: Cannot you change from admin area? Any reason for changing it from local.xml?

Comment: yes i could but I was assigned to do it from the local.xml because I'm doing an internship and they told me to do it that way so I would learn the "proper way". Just a weird request from them..

Comment: Well I changed it from the admin area, I'll ask them tomorrow how I was supposed to do it. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/change-products-per-page-for-individual-categories too.,

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code may it works

```
   <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
              <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
        </block>
   </reference>
```

Add above code in category handler those are

```
<catalog_category_default>
```

and

```
<catalog_category_layered>
```