# Change Product List Count and List Size Programmatically Via Layout Update XML

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, layout-update, pagination

I am trying to limit the products per page to six from the current twelve. Also trying to make the dropdown options 6, 12, 24 for different product displays. I currently have the file `../app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml` where I made the following changes in this block:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>

        <reference name="left_first">

            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
                    <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                    <!-- Since the addColumnCountLayoutDepend does not work, we are manually setting the max columns -->
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

As you can see I have added

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
```

to make these changes. I do not see any changes though. Not in products displayed nor in the dropdown where numbers can be selected. How come.

**NB** Themes now in /app/design/frontend are base, default and rdw (current package name).

**NBB** As shown in comments I can change dropdown values in backend config > catalog, but I somehow cannot change the no. of products shown that way by default. Twelve remain all the same.

[image: catalog]

Here is the full catalog list.phtml https://gist.github.com/jasperf/54815aeaa685a1b282675cf675dceb8a located at `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Comment: You can also change those values in the backend in System > Configuration > Catalog. Maybe you should give that a try too

Comment: Will have a look see there too. Thanks. Do hope to learn to do this in the code as well though.

Comment: Dropdown values I could change to 6,12,24, but though I indicated 6 per grid layout I still see 12 and then pagination

Comment: clear the cache @rhand

Comment: I agree with @RaphaelatDigitalPianism that this is a setting in Magento that you could adjust. Presuming you prefer editing this in the code itself, there could be multiple reasons why the change is not applied: the cache is not cleared (clear the `/var/cache/` directory) or maybe you're not editing the correct template file (i.e. you have a custom theme installed and you should edit those files instead of the ones from the default rwd theme).

Comment: @GopalPatel Does not seem to matter. All caches emptied multiple times and I still see twelve products on category page household/bedroom . Only dropdown changes are shown as 6,12,24 as changed in backend config. Somehow there is another default 12 somewhere that needs changing

Comment: What about the CSS/HTML itself? Maybe your theme has an override on that and doesn't care about the layout setting. Check if the column/element in the list has a specific width setup and also if the template contains something like: `<li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">`

Comment: @versedi at app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml I do have `<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?><?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?><?php endif*/ ?><li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">` That and specific pages/pages per column no loaded with case/breaks before that.

Comment: added link to list.phtml in question. But here once more just in case. Think the issue is there too now https://gist.github.com/jasperf/54815aeaa685a1b282675cf675dceb8a

Answer (score 1):

From your question I am not able to get if you have a default category view or a layered category view.
Update the same thing in `<catalog_category_default>` tag.
Also, update your code like below.

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager">
    <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>6</limit></action>
    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>6</limit></action>
    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>12</limit></action>
    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
<block>
```

You need to set these values inside `product_list_toolbar_pager` block. More [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34478/2443)