# Magento2 : Category List Page limited product view for a one category

Tags: magento2, category-products

I have a 5 or more categories. There is a specific category set for a 1-column-layout and another are as 2-column-left layout.

For a 1-column-layout category i want to show limited product like 6 product limit after that pagination will appear and same for second specific category show product 10 after that show pagination.

please see image.

[image]
In **Layout Update Xml** field add xml code for product limit.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#argument hope help you

Comment: @Nolwennig, i have used like that but it's not working. so can tell me that what should be issue there?
my code is like that in xml:

<referenceContainer name="content">  
     <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
                      <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
                            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
                        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: @Nolwennig, hello Have you get anything about this ... ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/34455/32047
Please check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i've tested and worked in my project:
This was related to module ***Magento_CatalogSearch etc/search_request.xml***
Step 1: create new module.
Step 2: create file etc/search_request.xml with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<requests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Search/etc/search_request.xsd">
    <request query="catalog_view_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
        <dimensions>
            <dimension name="scope" value="default"/>
        </dimensions>
        <queries>
            <query xsi:type="boolQuery" name="catalog_view_container" boost="1">
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="category"/>
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="price"/>
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="visibility"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="category">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="category_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="price">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="price_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="visibility">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="visibility_filter"/>
            </query>
        </queries>
        <filters>
            <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="category_filter" field="category_ids" value="$category_ids$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="rangeFilter" name="price_filter" field="price" from="$price.from$" to="$price.to$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="visibility_filter" field="visibility" value="$visibility$"/>
        </filters>
        <aggregations>
            <bucket name="price_bucket" field="price" xsi:type="dynamicBucket" method="$price_dynamic_algorithm$">
                <metrics>
                    <metric type="count"/>
                </metrics>
            </bucket>
            <bucket name="category_bucket" field="category_ids" xsi:type="termBucket">
                <metrics>
                    <metric type="count"/>
                </metrics>
            </bucket>
        </aggregations>
        <from>0</from>
        <!-- custom change size, which will make limit 10 products in category page -->
        <size>10</size>
    </request>
</requests>
```

Which actually change in the code is you set ***size = 10***, or what ever number you want.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml#L30) and on [Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Pager](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Pager.php#L138).

You can try with something like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar_pager">
    <action method="setLimit">
      <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
    </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

or using `xsi:type="number"` instead of `xsi:type="string"`:

```
<argument name="limit" xsi:type="number">3</argument>
                                 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: i have done same as above but it's not working

Comment: nothing in log?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still not any change i think there is a custom theme issue. if you have any idea about his then let me known thanks  once again.

Comment: try with built-in theme and compare processflowif needed

Answer (score -1):

As far as I am aware for this to work you need to have the value entered in Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values (Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront) then it is available to use via XML using:

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
         <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

see also - [Magento LayoutXML Update Default Products per Page Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284282/magento-layoutxml-update-default-products-per-page-grid/284286)